# How to make background transparent for Dojo button showing only icons

Tags: css, button, dojo, customization

I would like to control the button formating for dojo button so that only icon (image) remains visible - no dojo styling

Here is what I am doing: Creating button

```
var w = new Button({
type:"button",
iconClass: "infoIcon",
showLabel:"false",
onClick: function () {
openInfoPane(ProcessRowdata(grid, Data));
}
});
```

This button is placed in dojo Grid

here is CSS

```
.infoIcon {
background-image: url('images/help.ico');
width: 24px;
height: 24px;
background-color: transparent;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
padding:0px;
margin-left:4px;

}
```

Now it look like this - [IMG]http://i59.tinypic.com/2h540w3.png[/IMG]
I would like to get rid of background (blue glowing thing)

Some thing like - [IMG]http://i58.tinypic.com/2ijm6is.png[/IMG]
How to get this done?

seems that "background-color: transparent;" does not have any effect?

Answer (score 0):

```css
#navToolbar .tundra .dijitToolbar {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: No luck. I am not using toolbar? I am not if dijitToolbar will have any effect.